# How can i change a singleton object at runtime with guice?

Tags: java, multithreading, dependency-injection, reflection, guice

I am using Guice, and I have an immutable singleton object representing an endpoint configuration, which is provided to **many** other components.

I need to support a change of this endpoint at runtime, so every object with a reference to it, sees the "new" instance on every subsequent access.

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Use reflection to change the `instance` provided by the `Singleton#getInstance()` method

Comment: Unortunately it is a guice singleton, which means it is just injected in constructors. No "getInstance" exists

Comment: Is it possible to change the singleton after it has been injected? Do you store it in a variable?

Comment: If you can change the the singleton to a `Provider`, or you can implement your own custom scope https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes These are both under the assumption you can modify the module.